# Kivy: Is there a "BoundedString" property available for TextInputs?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way for `TextInput`s to receive a bounded string value (i.e., string of maximum length, x)? I tried investigating how to mixin `AliasProperty` in order to mimic `BoundedNumericProperty`, but can't find any Property class methods.

Comment: Y not just override `insert_text` and restrict the text entered into TextInput this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the time `on_text` is called text is already changed in the textinput. You want to override [insert_text](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.insert_text) to catch the text before it is inserted into the TextInput and thus before the [text](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.text) property is updated so as to restrict the entry to the TextInput.

Please don't bind/request the keyboard as the textinput does that for you and your handler will stop working after the Textinput is focused (TextInput would request the keyboard and in a single keyboard environment your handler will stop working).

Here is a sample code overriding insert_text to restrict text text entry to only numeric input.

```
class NumericInput(TextInput):

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if not from_undo:
            try:
                int(substring)
            except ValueError:
                return
        super(NumericInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo)
```

So For restricting the text to a certain length you could do the following::

```
class CustomInput(TextInput):

    max_chars = NumericProperty(10)

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if not from_undo and (len(self.text)+len(substring) > self.max_chars):
            return
        super(CustomInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo)
```

Comment: Gotta stop trying to reinvent the wheel. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the event `on_text` is triggered each time you modify the text.  So you can override the method:

```
def on_text(self, instance, value):
    print('The widget', instance, 'have:', value)

    # validate here!!!

    # you might also want to call the parent.
    #super(ClassName, self).on_text(instance, value)
```

Or bind it:

```
def my_callback(instance, value):
    print('The widget', instance, 'have:', value)
    #validate here

textinput = TextInput()
textinput.bind(text=my_callback)
```

**Be careful with the infinitive recursion**. If you modify the text variable inside `on_text` or `my_callback` you might be triggering the event ago. I honestly don't remember but I think it does, so you need a flag such as validating before modifying the variable

You can also use still use `on_focus` so you check when the `TextInput` lost focus:

```
def on_focus(instance, value):
    if value:
        print('User focused', instance)
    else:
        print('User defocused', instance)

textinput = TextInput()
textinput.bind(focus=on_focus)
```

Finally, you can also [bind the keyboard](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=keyboard#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.request_keyboard) so you will guarantee access before the `TextInput`. I honestly don't know the order of execution but if you use `on_text` you might be deleting after the letter appearing on the screen which might be undesirable.

I think implementing your own `BoundedStringProperty` would be quite a work to achieve what you want. Here is the code of [`BoundedNumericProperty`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx#L743)

Also, you shouldn't be trying to use an `AliasProperty` since you already got `StringProperty` that triggers the `on_text` event mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple problem with the code given above. you have to use NumericProperty.defaultvalue in order to use the code ( in the length comparison). Below is simple child class that can be used to create the classes for any size you deem fit.

```
class CustomInput(TextInput):

def  __init__(self , **kwargs):
    if "max_chars" in kwargs:
        self.max_chars = NumericProperty(int(kwargs["max_chars"]))
    super(CustomInput , self ).__init__(**kwargs)

def insert_text( self , substring , from_undo = False ):
    if not from_undo and ( len( self.text ) + len( substring ) > self.max_chars.defaultvalue ):
        return
    super( CustomInput , self).insert_text( substring , from_undo)
```

i pass max_chars as a keyword argument to the init.
this works if i use just int for max_chars instead of NumericProperty